# Are CopyTo and MoveTo in the FileInfo class atomic?

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io

I am writing a file processing component that checks a directory periodically and if a file shows up it copies that file to a separate network location.

`FileInfo.CopyTo` does what I need but if the file is large and is in the middle of being written will `CopyTo` wait (*or throw an exception*) or will it attempt to copy a partial file?

And is it the same for `MoveTo`?  I've searched MSDN and stackOverflow but can find no topics that address this question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, C# (.Net 4.0 specifically)

Comment: It entirely depends on the process that creates the file.  If it specified FileShare.Read then CopyTo will copy a partial file.  If it specified FileShare.None then CopyTo will fail if the process is still busy writing the file.  You could sniff by trying to open the file with FileShare.None